# How to run json-server in AWS?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, json-server

My team has deployed an Angular application in AWS. We used json-server for making mock service and database for the application. But, we can't find a way to run json-server in aws. Can anyone help us in this regard?

This is the pipeline code-

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
version: 0.2

env:
    variables:
        S3_BUCKET: "initial-codedeploy-bucket-us-east-1-jready"
        APP_NAME: "shopping-city"
        BUILD_ENV : "prod"

phases:
    install:
        commands:
        # Download and Install NodeJS 10.0
        - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
        - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
        - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
        # Install http drivers for node
        - sudo apt-get update -y
        - sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
        # Install Yarn Package Manager (Replace the commands below if you using NPM).
        # - curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
        # - echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
        - sudo apt-get update -y
        - sudo apt-get install -y npm
        # Install Angular CLI, If you are not using Angular 6, install angular/cli@1.7.0 or lower, confirm by running ng -v inside your project folder
        - npm global add @angular/cli@6.0.8
        # Install node dependancies.
        - npm install

build:
        commands:
        # Builds Angular application. You can also build using custom environment here like mock or staging
        - echo Build started on `date`
        - ng build --${BUILD_ENV}

post_build:
        commands:
        # Clear S3 bucket.
        - aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
        - echo S3 bucket is cleared.
        # Copy dist folder to S3 bucket, As of Angular 6, builds are stored inside an app folder in distribution and not at the root of the dist folder
        - aws s3 cp dist s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${APP_NAME} --recursive
        - echo Build completed on `date`

artifacts:
    files:
        - '/'
    discard-paths: yes
    base-directory: 'dist*'
```

Comment: You can use an EC2 instance with PM2 + Nginx, to get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run json-server on the AWS EÇ2, you need to run the following command:

```
nohup json-server --watch data/store.json --port
```

Then you can use curl to verify that the json-server is up and can respond to the request correctly.

If you want to use a port lower than 1024, run the command using `sudo`.

I can't call the api in the public network, maybe the issue of security group or some other permission isn't set properly. But I wish this can help.